# Dart crashes when calling toString() of the parent class

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I probably just simply overlooked something, but I have a simple class tree where the superclass has a simple toString() method. When calling it from the derived class instance, I get a crash in VS Code:

```
class Item {
  String status = "";
  String name = "";
  Item();

  String toString() {
    return "$this.name ($this.status)";
  }
}

class MiscItem extends Item {}

class FoodItem extends Item {}

class DrinkItem extends Item {}

DrinkItem coke1 = new DrinkItem();
print(coke1.toString());
```

Then it drops dead with:

```
===== CRASH =====
ExceptionCode=-1073741819, ExceptionFlags=0, ExceptionAddress=00007FF7E9F498FE
version=2.16.1 (stable) (Tue Feb 8 12:02:33 2022 +0100) on "windows_x64"
pid=14904, thread=14540, isolate_group=main(000001FED427C020), isolate=main(000001FED4295B80)
isolate_instructions=7ff7e9e15450, vm_instructions=7ff7e9e15460
Stack dump aborted because GetAndValidateThreadStackBounds failed.
Exited (3221226505)
```

What did I mess up here? AFAIK DrinkItem should inherit both the superclass' toString() method and the status and name properties. Still, calling DrinkItem's toString() crashes.

Comment: `"$this.member"` will recursively call `this.toString()` and go into an infinite loop that exhausts memory.  You want `"${this.member}"`.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

You need curly braces in your string interpolation:

```dart
String toString() {
  return "${this.name} (${this.status});
}
```

Otherwise, it will be equivalent to `"${this}.name (${this}.status)"` and hence recursively invoke your `toString()` method.

By the way, in Dart, you don't have to use `this` inside the class. You can simplify your `toString()` method to:

```dart
String toString() {
  return "$name ($status);
}
```

Comment: Aaaaah, thank you! I indeed forgot about using the curly brackets. I'm still practicing Dart. Have a nice day!